# Is ALF part of MDA?

Tags: mda

Action language for fUML (ALF) is a language based on fUML and Model-Driven Architecture is an approach which uses models to develop software.

But how is ALF related to Model-Driven Architecture (MDA)?

Answer (score 0):

MDA is an approach to software development. There are various languages which support this approach. UML is one of them. The Action Language for Foundational UML is a textual surface representation for UML modeling elements.